# Simple Merge Quadrupling Observation Numbers

Tags: r, merge

Turns out I shouldn't have trusted the source of my data. They left duplicate observations and didn't clean the data as well as I assumed. So this question is moot.

I am attempting to merge two data frames. I've done this many times in the past with great success (after weeding out typos). I've been beating my head against the wall with this one. I cannot find the issue. One file has only 6 columns, 4 of which are repeated in the larger file. I need to merge by unique combinations of these 4 columns. For instance, Plant 1 at Transect A at Site X in year 2014 should have only 1 row. Each Transect and Site have unique prefixes assigned to each plant, but I need to subset out by these 4 columns later, so I want to maintain them.

I've tried both cbind() and merge(). In merge I've also used all=true or false, since I know some of the rows are basically populated by NAs only and don't add anything to my analyses.

```
dat=cbind(dens, df)
dat=cbind(dens, df), by=c("Year", "site", "transect", "PlantID"))
```

or

```
dat=merge(dens, df, by=c("PlantID","Year", "site", "transect"), all=F)
```

These data files are both only just over 7000 observations in length. But when I cbind or merge, I get the same df, which is well over 10,000 observations. I've looked at the output and a good number of the individuals have been quadrupled. I'm sure it's something very simple that I've missed but at this point I need fresh and knowledgeable eyes.
Here is a link to the two data files on Google Drive.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JQXSadqxQBOXM5AAOFAr-BmuoX9TXKXh?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm trying to keep columns from both datasets. Both have the same observations, just different information about them and I need them to be combined. The reason why I'm confused here is because I have literally done this exact merge without issue before.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, when you merge you usually only use one primary key to merge on as multiple can be prone to issues. From your description is sounds like the keys you are using are not the same. For instance one dataset has column Col1 and the other has col1 or worse they are different data types, but they appear to be the same on screen. Maybe try taking a small subset of your datasets and trying merging those before throwing the whole process at it and being surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: I did double check that the data types and column names, I've made that mistake before. They're the same type and same names in both datasets.

Comment: I have also tried to combine using only one primary key to merge and that gave me an even larger data frame of around 56,000 observations.